React Native: dlopen failed: library 'libhermes_executor.so' not found (Hermes Engine Build Error)
I am working on a React Native project and facing a build/runtime error when trying to run the app on an Android device or emulator. The error seems related to the Hermes JavaScript engine and is as follows:
While BUILDING This error appeared
PLEASE DEVELOPERS HELP ME !
I am working on a React Native project and facing a build/runtime error when trying to run the app on an Android device or emulator. The error seems related to the Hermes JavaScript engine and is as follows:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libhermes_executor.so" not found
java.lang.Runtime.LoadLibrary0
java.lang.System.LoadLibrary
com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.SystemDelegate.LoadLibrary
com.facebook.soloader.nativeloader.NativeLoader.LoadLibrary
com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.LoadLibrary
com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit>
com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory
com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build

PLEASE DEVELOPERS HELP ME !
Reinstalled all project dependencies
Cleared React Native's cache
Even Clear the Cache in Android Studio before BUILD
Verified that all libraries are compatible with my React Native version
Reinstalled all project dependencies
Cleared React Native's cache
Even Clear the Cache in Android Studio before BUILD
Verified that all libraries are compatible with my React Native version

I encountered this problem and need to replace the onCreate function, in MainApplication.kt, just follow the steps - https://reactnative.dev/blog/2024/10/23/release-0.76-new-architecture#breaking-changes-1
